# Sharing data from multiple instances of a directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom directive which is re-usable throughout the application. This directive uses `ui-grid` and I'm trying to determine the "angular way" of allowing access to the grid API from anywhere in the application.

If it was only a single instance, I'd use a service to share data across controllers:

```
var attachments = angular.module('attachments', ['ui.grid']);

// this would be accessible from any of my controllers
attachments.factory('Attachments', function() {
    return {};
});

attachments.directive('attachments', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'attachments.html', // template has a ui-grid, among other elements
        controller: ['$scope', 'Attachments', function($scope, Attachments) {

            $scope.gridOptions = {
                // ui-grid code here
                onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
                    Attachments.grid = gridApi;
                }
            };
        }]
    };
});
```

However, there could be multiple instances of the directive

For example, there might be a primary instance of this directive and one inside a modal, or one in a sidebar, one in a modal, etc.

I suppose I could add property namespaces to that service...

```
Attachments = {
  libraryGrid: // ...
  someModalGrid: // ...
}
```

etc...

I'd prefer to avoid making a service for each possible instance, i.e.:

```
attachments.factory('SomeModalAttachments', function() {
    return {};
});
```

While it would work it feels inefficient. However, both choices are a lot better than digging into the modal scope and finding child scopes with the necessary API.

Is there any other method I haven't considered?

Answer (score 0):

To me it depends on your usage model.

If you're going to have multiple of these and other bits of the application are going to access them, then that means one of a few things:

1. The access is actually initiated from the grid.  So you have perhaps many list pages, and the currently active list page is the one you want to deal with.  So I'd have the grid register with all the things it wants to talk to, and deregister when it closes again.  The other things would all be services (singletons).
2. There are a specified number of these grids, and you talk to them by name - so you want to interact with the list-page-grid, or the modal-grid or whatever.  So you have each grid register with somewhere central (maybe a service that everything else talks to).
3. The grids are subsidiary to something.  So a page includes the grid directive, and then that page wants to talk to that grid.  You could pass an object into the directive, then have the grid register itself on that object.  So you call the directive with "myGridCommunicationObject = {}", and then the grid does "$scope.myGridCommunicationObject.gridApi = gridApi".  This doesn't let other bits of the application talk to the grid, but if really you only want whatever created the grid to talk to it, then it works well.
4. You could broadcast.  So if you don't really care which grid you talk to, you just want to talk to any grid that's currently visible (say you're resizing them or something) you could just broadcast an event to them, and all your grid directives could listen for that event.  Taking this one step further, you could broadcast and include a grid id or name in the parameter, and then have each grid check whether it's me before taking action.

Having said all those options, there's something about what you're doing that has a bit of a code smell to it.  Really, arbitrary bits of the application shouldn't want to talk directly to the grid Api, they should be communicating with methods on the controller that holds the grid.  Perhaps some examples of what you want to do would help, but it feels to me like the model should be one of the grid registering to use other services (e.g. resize notifications), or of the controller that owns the grid interacting with the grid, and other things interacting with that controller.

Comment: Thanks, some of these ideas are worth considering. This application is a complete rewrite from a decade-old web app, so adjusting my thought process is a bit of work. The need for external resources to "access the grid" won't be terribly common, but a good example is when a sidebar panel wants to programmatically tell the grid which rows to mark selected. The non-angular app has some cruddy `app.mainGrid.setSelectedRows()` call. Maybe your suggestion of passing the component (sidebar) to the attachments grid instead (and listening for an event) would be better?

Comment: You could pass the sidebar to the grid.  But if it's mostly that there are some things outside your control that can tell you to select certain rows, presumably that thing also knows which of the grids it wants to communicate with.  So maybe the broadcast idea is a better one - it calls `app.setSelectedRows('mainGrid', row_ids)` and that function internally just broadcasts, any grid directives that are rendered listen for that broadcast, check whether the grid that was requested is them, then apply it

Comment: But equally you could just be a bit bodgy, and just have each grid set something on `$rootScope`.  So `$rootScope.grids['mainGrid'] = $scope`.  Then you write a wrapper somewhere that allows grid communication, and it internally just does `$rootScope.grids['mainGrid'].gridApi.dostuff`.  The external app calls that wrapper.  You could get the same effect more elegantly with a service, but $rootScope also works.  If you go the service route, then the directive includes the service and does `gridHandler.grids['mainGrid'] = $scope` same as in $rootScope, but you just get at it with the service.

Comment: And thinking for those 2 seconds extra....really the gridHandler service should have `gridHandler.addGridScope( 'mainGrid', $scope )` rather than just writing to it directly.  Although either works.